# 693Mb listing of ubuntu 12.04 downloas to 726MB?

Tags: 12.04, live-cd, macbook

I just downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 for mac, the download said 693MB. Great, that will fit on a CD. Downloaded it, and it is 726MB? what? I have a macbook a1181 with no os, and only cds to work with. What is going on here? Can I actually burn this to a cd? Is this a misprint or something on the website?

Download link here http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64+mac.iso

Comment: Get a DVD, or buy a USB stick (or borrow it). See [here (Windows)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and [here (OS X)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx). A (better) alternative is to download [Lucid Lynx](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/) create its live CD and then create the live USB using Ubuntu (or you could even install Lucid and then upgrade it if you have a good internet connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just classic confusion between MegaBytes ( base 10 ) and so called MebiBytes ( base 2 ).  In base 2 units, a MB = 1024 KB, and a KB = 1024 bytes, so 693 MB = 693 * 1024 * 1024 or 726,663,168 bytes.  So the image is in fact 693 MB.

Comment: This raises some more questions for me, but it worked, so i'm happy! Also reporting that my macbook runs 12.04 very well.

Answer (score 2):

Most people are using usb drives these days are they are easily available, reusable, and less expensive.

At any rate, some .iso are larger then 700 mb but burn to iso with no problem.

If you wish to use a CD, burn it and report any problems.

Comment: yeah I don’t care what most people are doing. I have limited resources, specifically 2 cds from which to make this work, and it is not documented very well. One might assume a live-cd would burn to a CD; else it might be called a live-dvd. 

So I Burned the 726MB iso to a 700MB cd? ok I guess. Then installed just fine.